# Insert many foreign-key related records in one query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to come up with a single query that helps me atomically normalise a table (populate a new table with initial values from another table, *and simultaneously add the foreign key reference to it*)

Obviously populating one table from another is a standard `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`, but I also want to update the foreign key reference in the 'source' table to reference the new record in the 'new' table.

Let's say I am migrating a schema from:

```sql
CREATE TABLE companies (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  address_line_1 TEXT,
  address_line_2 TEXT,
  address_line_3 TEXT
)
```

to:

```sql
CREATE TABLE addresses (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  line_1 TEXT,
  line_2 TEXT,
  line_3 TEXT
)
CREATE TABLE companies (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  address_id INTEGER REFERENCES addresses(id)
)
```

... I thought perhaps a CTE might help of the form

```sql
WITH new_addresses AS (
  INSERT INTO addresses (line_1, line_2, line_3)
  SELECT address_line_1, address_line_2, address_line_3
  FROM companies
  RETURNING id, companies.id AS company_id -- DOESN'T WORK
)
UPDATE companies
SET address_id = new_addresses.id
FROM new_addresses
WHERE new_addresses.company_id = companies.id
```

It seems that RETURNING can only return data from the inserted record however, so this will not work

I assume at this point that the answer will be to either use PLSQL or incorporate domain knowledge of the data to do this in a multi step process. My current solution is pretty much:

```sql
-- FIRST QUERY
-- ensure address record IDs will be in the same sequential order as their relating companies
INSERT INTO addresses (line_1, line_2, line_3)
SELECT address_line_1, address_line_2, address_line_3
FROM companies
ORDER BY id;

-- SECOND QUERY
-- join, making the assumption that the table IDs are in the same order
WITH address_ids AS (
  SELECT id AS address_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS idx
  FROM addresses
), company_ids AS (
  SELECT id AS company_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS idx
  FROM companies
), company_address_ids AS (
  SELECT company_id, address_id
  FROM address_ids
  JOIN company_ids USING (idx)
)
UPDATE companies
SET address_id = company_address_ids.address_id
FROM company_address_ids
WHERE id = company_address_ids.company_id
```

This is obviously problematic in that it relies on the addresses table containing exactly as many records as the company table, but such a query would be a one-off when the table is first created.

Comment: You have to define your FKs as `deferrable` and then wrap your SQL statements in a transaction. Once you finish the initial seeding - you can redefine the FKs to be `non-deferrable`.

Comment: Hi Ivo, thanks for the reply. Yeah, I know I can perform the update as a composite set of queries, I was just wondering if theres a magic way to do it in one query

Comment: Well, if you rely on sequences/autoincrement PKs - then you will have to generate those PKs in your SELECT and then in the INSERT you need to include both the source PK and the own PK of the record. Then RETURNING will have access both to the PKs in the source table and to the PK in the new table, so it can update the FK with the corresponding ID. It sounds a little messy but I hope you can get the idea.

Comment: _Then RETURNING will have access both to the PKs in the source table and to the PK in the new table_

I don't think this is true - that was what I was trying in the CTE expression above

Comment: ROW_NUMBER won't necessarily match your PK - neither from `addresses` nor from `companies`. Like I said - you will have to include `companies.id` into the SELECT and thus into the INSERT to allow it being available for RETURNING. Once you do the feed - you can safely delete this extra column from your table.